# Number of Erlang nodes possible/practical?

Tags: erlang

1) What's the largest theoretical number of nodes that can exist in an Erlang network ('theoretical' perhaps meaning 'whatever is allowed or disallowed by the language')?

2) What's the practical number of nodes that can exist in an Erlang network?  I know this could probably vary hugely depending on a variety of factors.  If you want to throw me some numbers, you can assume each node is a separate machine accessible through the internet, not through a LAN (I assume this is possible?), and each machine is simply a 'generic desktop PC' of average performance.  In fact, you can assume 'average' for anything you need an assumption for (average latency, average bandwidth i.e. cable modem, etc).

3) What's the largest number of nodes in an Erlang network that is known to have existed?

Related to above questions... doesn't each node keep a tcp connection to all other nodes?  So if you were to have thousands of nodes... ?

If it makes any difference, I'm not asking these questions for trivia purposes.  They are exploratory questions for a possible project.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know why this question is considered 'too broad.'  It seemed specific enough to me, and the answerer below seemed to have understood it well enough and answered it sufficiently, thus it was the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) unlimited, Erlang the language does not it self specify any limitations to this. It will depend on the runtime implementation.

2) Normally I would not use Erlang's built in distribution for doing things over the internet. Firewalls tend to screw things up a lot, and the current implementation is not really aimed at that use case. Rather it is meant to be used in a LAN where you have more control over the environment.

If you do want to connect nodes using over the Internet then you should do so using another protocol built on top of the tcp stack.

3) I've heard of people getting it a bit over 100, but after that things start to degenerate because all nodes are connected in a full mesh.

For a larger discussion have a look at this: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#fallacies-of-distributed-computing

Comment: Pretty much everything I was looking for - thanks.