# Erlang concurrency/distribution - then vs. now

Tags: concurrency, erlang, distributed-computing

As to the question of how many nodes can be in an erlang system on a practical (not theoretical) level, I've seen answers ranging from 100 in most cases, to one answer which stated "150-200 max."

I was surprised on seeing this, because wasn't erlang designed for massive concurrency and distribution in order to implement telecom networks, phone switches, etc?  If so, wouldn't you assume (I know I did) that this would entail more than 100 nodes in a system (I always assumed in the hundreds, possibly thousands)?

I guess my question is:  What was considered "massive concurrency/distribution" back when these old telecoms used erlang?  How many machines would they typically have connected together, running erlang and doing concurrency?

Just curious, and thanks for any answers.

Comment: The aim of this site is more to help people to find a solution to their actual problems. For general discussion I imagine that there are other places to do so. To build my own opinion on the OTP environment I have made some application, read documentation (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content is really good to start) and tried to figure out how works some big applications such as Riak

Comment: This isn't "general discussion."  I asked a question, I didn't solicit discussion.

Comment: I hate this tendency to close any question that involves ballpark performance figures. Sure it will depend on lots of things, but so does everything. It's entirely possible to give useful answer to this question that isn't "entirely based on opinions".

Comment: @Enno - I agree 100%.  It happened to me here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354804/number-of-erlang-nodes-possible-practical/20355867?noredirect=1#20355867 funny thing is, someone understood exactly what I wanted and answered perfectly.

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like the proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal as well

Answer (score 2):

you got the answer, for a cluster of node, with current technology, a practical limit is from 100 to 200 nodes: because we are speaking of almost transparent distribution. The reason for this limitation are explained in the documentation and in few words are due to the mutual survey of each nodes, so the bandwidth and resources available for your application are decreasing faster and faster.

To have more nodes, you must program the cooperation between cluster and/or single nodes. The libraries offer some facilities to do that but of course it is not transparent, and not erlang specific.

It is also recommended for security reason to avoid huge cluster: today in an erlang cluster you can do what you want in any other node without restriction.

Comment: Maybe you can improve your answer by giving explicit examples, it seems a bit too general in its current form.

Comment: You are saying that back in the olden days, Ericsson or whoever would run between 100-200 machines hooked together to implement their telecom switching and what not?  I always envisioned thousands, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It depends on lots of things you didn't specify or define, and I suspect that if you specified enough that a "real" answer was possible you would be disappointed because it wouldn't be useful. That's why these sorts of questions are generally discouraged.

You don't say what date range you mean by "when these old telecoms used Erlang". They still use it (it's never had traction outside of Ericsson and there was never a time when Ericsson used it significantly more than the present). Here's a video of them talking about using Erlang on their [SGSN-MME](http://www.ericsson.com/ourportfolio/products/sgsn-mme): http://vimeo.com/44718243

You don't say what you mean by "an Erlang system". Is that a single machine? Erlang did not have SMP support when it started (is that the time frame you're asking about?). Do you mean concurrent processes?

Is that a single cluster using `net_kernel:connect_node/1`? How are you defining a cluster? Erlang clusters, by default, are a complete mesh. That limits the maximum size based on the performance limits of the network and the machine's interfaces. But you can connect nodes in a chain and then there's no limit. But if you count that as a cluster, why not count it when you use your own TCP connections instead of just net_kernel's. There are lots of Ericsson routers in use on the Internet, so we could think of the Internet as one "system" where many of its component routers are using Erlang.

In the video I linked, you can see that in the early 2000s, Ericsson's SGSN product was a single box (containing multiple machines) that could serve maybe a few thousand mobile phones simultaneously. We might assume that each connected phone had one Erlang process managing it, plus a negligible number of system processes.

Comment: I initially specified a lot, but the question was put on hold.  Ironically, by deleting most of the specificity, the question was posted.  Date range is simply "back when Erlang was invented."  An "Erlang system" is the generic system they had functioning to do whatever it was they invented Erlang to do.  You say Erlang didn't have SMP support back then.  Then why, pray tell, all the hooplah about it's "concurrency?"

Comment: First, because of concurrency between computers. Second, because even if you only have a single core (and so nothing is ever technically concurrent) threading is still really hard and everyone messes it up.

Comment: Concurrency betw. computers... you mean an Erlang cluster?  And sure I agree on the threading point.

Comment: Yes, an Erlang cluster. If you don't care about the details of networking, memory, and processor cache, there's not a ton of difference between a single multi-processor machine and a cluster of multiple single-processor machines.